# How to turn a JS code into a do-while ReCaptcha loop?

Tags: javascript, html, math, do-while

I can't seem to modify the js part of the code into a do-while loop instead. I have tried this

do {text+=possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*5))}
while (i<5);

but I'm pretty sure it's incorrect.

```html
do {text+=possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*5))}
while (i<5);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Simple JavaScript Captcha Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* Function to Generat Captcha */
function GenerateCaptcha() {
var chr1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)+ '';
var chr2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)+ '';
var chr3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)+ '';
var chr4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)+ '';
var chr5 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)+ '';
var chr6 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)+ '';
var chr7 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)+ '';
 
var captchaCode = chr1 + chr2  + chr3  + chr4 + chr5+ chr6  + chr7;
document.getElementById("txtCaptcha").value = captchaCode
} 
/* Validating Captcha Function */
function ValidCaptcha() {
var str1 = document.getElementById('txtCaptcha').value;
var str2 = document.getElementById('txtCompare').value;
 
if (str1 == str2) return true;
return false;
}
 
/* Remove spaces from Captcha Code */
function removeSpaces(string) {
return string.split('').join('');
}
</script>
 
</head>
<body onload="GenerateCaptcha();">
<h2>Generating Captcha Demo</h2>
<input type="text" id="txtCaptcha" style="text-align: center; border: none; font-weight: bold; font-family: Modern" />
<input type="button" id="btnrefresh" value="Refresh" onclick="GenerateCaptcha();" />
<input type="text" id="txtCompare" />
<input id="btnValid" type="button" value="Check" onclick="alert(ValidCaptcha());" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see you defined `i` and incremented it in loop, instead try `text.length < 5`.

Comment: _"but I'm pretty sure it's incorrect"_ - Why do you think this is incorrect? -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Is there anything not working with the given code? Also, please do not use irrelevent tags - otherwise, please explain how this question is related to HTML